# Calling a re-instantiated async task failing with 'task has already been executed'

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a search task which when the button is clicked a second time, it cancels the currently running task and recreates it.

```
if (_searchAsyncTask != null) {
    // cancel if already running
    _searchAsyncTask.cancel(true);
}
_searchAsyncTask = new SearchAsyncTask(this);
_searchAsyncTask.execute(data);
```

This is failing on the last line in the above code as if I had called the original async task again.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to wait until the original instance isCancelled()?

Comment: On the surface, can't fault your code at all. You are firing a new instance so you really shouldn't be getting that exception. Are you by any chance resuming the app in between (from background) or something to that effect?

Comment: Also which version of Android is this running on?

Comment: This is coming from debug info from test users, I specifically found the 'second execution' issue and replaced with this, so I am quite surprised to see it. It is running on 4.0.3

Comment: Not quite sure how they triggered this so might try causing resume.

Comment: Let me post in the answer section as what I want to say will not fit here. I was reluctant to post as answer due to the fact that I don't know the actual problem... :p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6879609/2624806 might help here :)

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had this odd problem where it was bombing out with a similar exception when resuming from background and the task had been running halfway through when it went to the background. I switched to using AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor to fix this (some code may be redundant):

```
if (_searchAsyncTask == null) {
    _searchAsyncTask = new SearchAsyncTask();
}

if (mThreadExecutor != null && !mThreadExecutor.isShutdown()) {
    mThreadExecutor.shutdownNow();
}

if (mThreadExecutor == null || mThreadExecutor.isShutdown()) {
    mThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

if (_searchAsyncTask.getStatus() != Status.RUNNING) {
    _searchAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(mThreadExecutor);
}
```

This solved my problems. You might want to give it a shot...?

Comment: I've still not been able to recreate this issue so I am going to chalk it up to an issue with the bug reporting, or a glitchy build. Voting to delete. Thanks for the time @dineth