# Unable to retrieve data from azure easy table & bind it to a List in Android Studio

Tags: android, azure, android-asynctask

I'm developing an Android App and I've created an App services in Azure & I've been trying to understand how to communicate with the DB through the MobileAppServices.

I was successful to Add items into the Tables (Easy tables) but, I couldn't retrieve data from the tables.

I've tried in 2 ways:

Retrieving data with/without AsyncTask.

(1)  I get An error. (Using AsyncTask)

```
public void onClickVerify(View view)  {

        if (mClient == null)
            return;

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    final List<Users> URS = GetItemsFromMobileServiceTable();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Verified = "Account is not Verified";
                            for (Users i : URS) {
                                if (i.getUN() == null)
                                    break;

                                else if( i.getUN() == Username.toString()) {
                                    Verified = "Account Verified";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception e) {}

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

        runAsyncTask(task);

    }


   private List<Users> GetItemsFromMobileServiceTable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, MobileServiceException {
        return mUser.where().field("UN").eq(Username.toString()).execute().get();
    }
```

> ```
>                                               --------- beginning of crash 03-14 12:40:54.623 3500-3500/com.himk.karam.h
> ```
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: com.himk.karam.h, PID: 3500
>                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4725)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4720)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
>                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the
>   task is already running.
>                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:609)
>                                                                       at com.himk.karam.h.Login.runAsyncTask(Login.java:183)
>                                                                       at com.himk.karam.h.Login.onClickVerify(Login.java:114)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4720) 
>                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
>                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

(2) when launching the Activity that contains that Retrieving action the Activity doesn't load.(without using AsynTask)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    try {
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://khim.azurewebsites.net",this);

        mClient.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(new OkHttpClientFactory() {
            @Override
            public OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                client.setWriteTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                return client;
            }
        });

        List<Users> mUsers = mClient.getTable(Users.class).execute().get();//if I remove this line the activity will load normally       
        Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUN);
    } catch (MalformedURLException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException | MobileServiceLocalStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

NOTE: ALL I WANT TO DO IS TO HAVE THE DATA IN A LIST IN ANDROID I DON'T WANT TO VIEW IT TO THE USER.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.` As the exception itself explains, you cannot execute an **AsyncTask** more than once. You can check out [this similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879584/how-to-run-the-same-asynctask-more-than-once) on SO for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aaron Chen points out, the exception is about executing AsyncTask more than once. In your #1 implementation using AsyncTask, the task is executed twice. First time in `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){@Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { /*...*/ }.execute();`, the second time in `mUser.where().field("UN").eq(Username.toString()).execute().get();`. If you remove the execute() from the first one, it should work just fine.

In your #2 implementation, the activity doesn't load because you're running an async query on UI thread in `onCreate()` method. If you run it on a background thread, this problem will go away. You can check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#a-namequeryingahow-to-query-data-from-your-mobile-app-backend) azure documentation on how to query data from your Mobile App backend. There's plenty of examples that should be helpful.